# RoR: Handling Blanks AND/OR Special Characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm processing emails for upload and occasionally an embedded image in the email comes through either without a file extension or with an extension containing a random combination of letters, numbers and special characters (for example: **image001.gif@01CFA02B.47556390**).  If either instance arrives, I want to ignore it and move on.  I think I've got the without extension covered, but wasn't clear on how best to handle the random characters and well as the cleanest way in to write the conditionals.  Here is what I have so far:

```
 filename_extension = File.extname(filename)

if filename_extension.blank?
              puts "FILENAME EXT IS BLANK"
    elsif filename_extension #NEED REGEX or something to handle Random?
            puts "FILENAME EXT IS Random"
          else #DO PROCESSING
```

Thanks.

Comment: so anything with a special character is considered random?

Comment: IMO your best bet would be to explicitly check for "allowed" extensions, and assume non-matches are random, unless you know the exact format(s) of the "random" chars.

Comment: Why aren't you just relying on the MIME type?

Comment: I'm using Mailgun, and it views the image as an attachment (multipart/form-data).  I'm not familiar with MIME will look into it.

Comment: As for allowed extensions, whatever is sent is as an actual attachment, whether its a PDF, image or some obscure attachment, is permitted, so the list of allowed would be extremely long.  Thanks.

Comment: This is tagged `ruby` so there is a problem with the code.  `blank?` gives a NoMethodError on Ruby 2.1.3, and others.  Unless you have defined that method.

Comment: Is the list of allowed longer than the list of not allowed?  I guess just don't know what wouldn't be allowed as an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
known_extensions = %w[.csv .rb .rbw .html .htm .css]
filenames = %w[1.txt 2.csv 3]
filenames.each do |filename|
  filename_extension = File.extname(filename)

  if filename_extension.empty?
    puts "FILENAME EXT IS BLANK"
  elsif known_extensions.include? filename_extension
    puts "FILENAME EXT IS Random"
  else #DO PROCESSING
    puts "Processing"
  end
end
```

The question was tagged `ruby` without any indicate of gems that may give you the `blank?` method.

The idea of an 'invalid' extension is rather varied, and of course tied to what it means to be a valid file name.  On most Unix file systems, for example, the only limitations on an file name would the limitation of the filename size of 255 bytes, and the reserved characters of `/` and `null`.  In fact, there is no specification that I am aware of about 'extensions' in Unix, as they are simply a part of a file name, the period in a file name being valid, not signifying anything special. (With the exception of a file name that starts with a period indicating that it should be a 'hidden' file.)  On a Windows system, it is a longer list of characters, some of which are `/ : < > ? \ | + , . ; = [ ]` as well as the single and double quotes.  On my Commodore, I think it was `:`, `,` and `=`, and on my Amiga system I could use anything except for `"`, `:`, or `/`.

So I think 'invalid' extension might be easier to match than the 'valid' ones.  If you are indeed using Rails, and hosting on Unix, then you have a smaller set of things to check for, to ensure a valid extension (indeed, a valid filename).  Basing that invalid extension on your hosting system, and any restrictions you would place due to your idea of what a valid extension means to your program.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I accommodate for allowing virtually any valid extension, just not those with something like: .gif@01CFA02B.47556390 or whatever it decides to be?  It could wind up being .psd#1BC2DEF.2010, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Define "valid extension".  Is the extension in your first example `.gif` or `.47556390`.  I noticed that someone other than you changed the tags on the question, but because it was not you, there is some potential that you are not using Rails.  Can you modify your question to confirm the changes that were made in your tags?